# How to use JavaScript to control the movement of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my code. There is a blue outlined ball with a white interior inside of a black rectangle css canvas. I'm looking to move this ball left, right, up and down using the arrow keys without being able to push the ball pass the boundaries of the black space. It works perfectly if you only tap the arrow key once in a consecutive direction but if you were to hold any of the arrow keys down it goes beyond the boundaries I have set in place to stop it from going past the black space. The function "topStop();" is one of 8 functions that I'm using to hinder the ball from exiting the black space but I'm kinda at a road block when it comes when someone holds the arrow keys down.

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <style>
        #blueBall {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #blueCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #000;
            width: 932px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            height: 512px;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        #pixelTrackerTop {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10%;
        }

        #pixelTrackerLeft {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 5%;
        }
      </style>
      <title>Animating Text</title>
      <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/
         ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">     </script>
      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
                  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);
         var topY = 0;
         var leftX = 0;

         function moveUp() {
             var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
             topY = topY -= 1;
             Y.style.top = topY;
             masterTrack();
             stopUp = setTimeout("moveUp()", 1)
             topStop();
             stopConflictYup();
             console.log('moveUp');
         };

         function moveDown() {
             var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
             topY = topY += 1;
             Y.style.top = topY;
             masterTrack();
             stopDown = setTimeout("moveDown()", 1)
             topStop();
             stopConflictYdown();
             console.log('moveDown');
         };

         function moveLeft() {
             var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
             leftX = leftX -= 1;
             X.style.left = leftX;
             masterTrack();
             stopLeft = setTimeout("moveLeft()", 1)
             leftStop();
             stopConflictXleft();
             console.log('moveLeft');
         };

         function moveRight() {
             var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
             leftX = leftX += 1;
             X.style.left = leftX;
             masterTrack();
             stopRight = setTimeout("moveRight()", 1)
             leftStop();
             stopConflictXright();
             console.log('moveRight');
         };

         function masterTrack() {
             var pxY = topY;
             var pxX = leftX;
             document.getElementById('pixelTrackerTop').innerHTML =
                 'Top position is ' + pxY;
             document.getElementById('pixelTrackerLeft').innerHTML =
                 'Left position is ' + pxX;
         };

         function topStop() {
             if (topY <= 0) {
                 clearTimeout(stopUp);
                 console.log('stopUp activated');
             };
             if (topY >= 500) {
                 clearTimeout(stopDown);
                 console.log('stopDown activated');
             };
         };

         function leftStop() {
             if (leftX <= 0) {
                 clearTimeout(stopLeft);
                 console.log('stopLeft activated');
             };
             if (leftX >= 920) {
                 clearTimeout(stopRight);
                 console.log('stopRight activated');
             };
         };

         function stopConflictYup() {
             clearTimeout(stopDown);
         };

         function stopConflictYdown() {
             clearTimeout(stopUp);
         };

         function stopConflictXleft() {
             clearTimeout(stopRight);
         };

         function stopConflictXright() {
             clearTimeout(stopLeft);
         };

         function keyBoardInput() {
             var i = event.keyCode;
             if (i == 38) {
                 if (topY > 0) {
                     moveUp();
                 };
             };
             if (i == 40) {
                 if (topY < 500) {
                     moveDown();
                 };
             };
             if (i == 37) {
                 if (leftX > 0) {
                     moveLeft();
                 };
             };
             if (i == 39) {
                 if (leftX < 920) {
                     moveRight();
                 };
             };
         };

      </SCRIPT>
   </head>
   <div id="blueCanvas">
      <div id="blueBall"></div>
   </div>
   <p id ="pixelTrackerTop">topTracker</p>
   <br>
   <p id ="pixelTrackerLeft">leftTracker</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you give us a specific piece of code that isn't functioning the way you want it to? It makes it easier to find the problem you're having.

Comment: The current code is working as intended, its the lack of code that is the problem, looking for a way to answer the original question of not allowing the ball to go past the black space when an arrow key is held down. I was thinking probably modifying the if statements that are attached to the keystroke or maybe adding a true/false clause to the functions that execute the movement. Im not sure how to solve this problem

Comment: Any chance you could create a working demo codepen with your code as it is now? I've tried copying it over myself but I can't get the ball moving.

Comment: where did you copy it to? try notepad++ and then run in chrome, thats how ive been working on it. code pen didnt work for me.

Comment: Ok that worked, but I can't reproduce the case where the ball leaves the box if you hold down the arrow keys. It stops perfectly at the edge. Chrome 53/Mac.

Comment: try holding the right arrow (or any arrow) key down for an extended period of time whilst its moving

Comment: I Just tried  if (topY < 1) {
 topY = 0;
 Y.style.top = topY;
 };  and it seems to work as long as i place it in the bottom of the move function. its kinda like a backstop for if it goes beyond -1.. still experimenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured out a way to bypass the computers logic in regards to rerunning the code that forces it off the black space. the code is as follows (first i will post the modifications and then i will post entire code page)

```
***MODIFCATIONS***


if (topY < 1) {
topY = 0;
Y.style.top = topY;
};

if (topY > 500) {
topY = 500;
Y.style.top = topY;
};

if (leftX < 1) {
leftX = 0;
Y.style.leftX = leftX;
};

if (leftX > 920) {
leftX = 920;
Y.style.leftX = leftX;
};


***ENTIRE CODE***

<html>
<head>
<style>
#blueBall {
position:relative;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid blue;
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-radius: 100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}

#blueCanvas {
position:absolute;
background-color:black;
width:932px;
border:1px solid black;
height:512px;
top:20px;
left:20px;
}

#pixelTrackerTop {
position:absolute;
bottom: 10%;
}

#pixelTrackerLeft {
position:absolute;
bottom: 5%;
}
</style>

<title>Portfolio</title>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);

var topY = 0;
var leftX = 0;

function moveUp() {




var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
topY = topY -= 1;
Y.style.top = topY;
masterTrack();

if (topY < 1) {
topY = 0;
Y.style.top = topY;
};

stopUp = setTimeout("moveUp()", 1)
topStop();
stopConflictYup();
console.log('moveUp');




};

function moveDown() {

var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
topY = topY += 1;
Y.style.top = topY;
masterTrack();

if (topY > 500) {
topY = 500;
Y.style.top = topY;
};

stopDown = setTimeout("moveDown()", 1)
topStop();  
stopConflictYdown();
console.log('moveDown');



};

function moveLeft() {

var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
leftX = leftX -= 1;
X.style.left = leftX;
masterTrack();

if (leftX < 1) {
leftX = 0;
Y.style.leftX = leftX;
};

stopLeft = setTimeout("moveLeft()", 1)
leftStop();
stopConflictXleft();
console.log('moveLeft');
};

function moveRight() {

var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
leftX = leftX += 1;
X.style.left = leftX;
masterTrack();

if (leftX > 920) {
leftX = 920;
Y.style.leftX = leftX;
};

stopRight = setTimeout("moveRight()", 1)
leftStop();
stopConflictXright();
console.log('moveRight');
};

function masterTrack()  {
var pxY = topY;
var pxX = leftX;
document.getElementById('pixelTrackerTop').innerHTML = 
'Top position is ' +   pxY;
document.getElementById('pixelTrackerLeft').innerHTML = 
'Left position is ' + pxX;
};

function topStop() {

if (topY <= 0) {
clearTimeout(stopUp);

console.log('stopUp activated');
};

if (topY >= 500) {
clearTimeout(stopDown);
console.log('stopDown activated');
};
};

function leftStop() {

if (leftX <= 0) {
clearTimeout(stopLeft);
console.log('stopLeft activated');
};

if (leftX >= 920) {
clearTimeout(stopRight);
console.log('stopRight activated');
};
};

function stopConflictYup() {
clearTimeout(stopDown);
};  

function stopConflictYdown(){
clearTimeout(stopUp);
};

function stopConflictXleft() {
clearTimeout(stopRight);
};

function stopConflictXright() {
clearTimeout(stopLeft);
};



function keyBoardInput() {
var i = event.keyCode;

if (i == 38) {
if(topY > 0) {
moveUp();
}; 

};

if (i == 40) {
if(topY < 500) {
moveDown();
};

};

if (i == 37) {
if(leftX > 0) {
moveLeft();
};
};

if (i == 39) {
if(leftX < 920) {
moveRight();
};
};
};

</SCRIPT>  
</head>

<div id="blueCanvas">
<div id="blueBall">
</div>
</div>

<p id ="pixelTrackerTop">topTracker</p>
    <br>
<p id ="pixelTrackerLeft">leftTracker</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahha Nice one. but if you wanna optimize your code then should check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589516(v=vs.85).aspx its awesome

Comment: Thx, just looked at link, its very concise and efficient, cant wait till i get to that level of coding!